# Beside using a dictionary, is there a better way to tie a gameobject and a non-monobehavior class at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a generic case I believe, where I have a NPC class with stats and parameters that has to be updated while the game progress (imagine fatigue for an athlete that play a soccer game).

And I have a gameobject, which has a mesh an animator component and other components (scripts, monobehavior), to perform specific functionalities.

Now; if you have 2,5,10 NPC that's not a big deal, but if you have plenty; that need an update on various parameters, you may get a feeling for the issue here.

So far I have a dictionary, which has as key the class NPC, and as value the gameobject; so I can create the NPC gameobject at runtime, and "relate" a NPC class instance to that specific gameobject. This seems to work just fine, but the fact that it works is not a proof of being efficient.

Am I risking anything, using this approach? Or there is a better way? I did read somewhere that all problems disappear if all classes are monobehavior; although I was not able to see a practical comparison.

Comment: Why not adding a component/behavior that holds the reference to the class object?

Comment: tell me more, please...this is new to me

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use such lists or dictionaries, since all lookups will take time, especially considering Unity already offers a component based system, so just create your own component for this.

I can post more details later, but basically create a new MonoBehavior like `ClassNPC` and add a public member to it that holds a reference to your class information object (e.g. `public ClassInfo usedClass`).

You can then use `GetComponent().usedClass' to access it (getting or setting).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought about this solution, but it imply to use a monobehavior class; while my NPC class is just a standard C# class. Also isn't the action of add at runtime the component on the gameobject, and then retrieve it with GetComponent(), more expensive than a lookup in a dictionary?

Comment: @newbiez Not necessarily. It could be optimized behind the scenes, so it always returns the n-th component attached to this entity, i.e. becoming trivial. I don't know the actual implementation. It's the preferred way and outside your code's scope, so don't worry about it unless it becomes a performance issue.

Comment: I see; in my case I have a simple entity class which hold the NPC data/parameters; and since it was never meant to be processed by the UI, I made it as regular class. At this point I should make it as a monobehavior and go on with that. BTW it doesn't matter if I apply the reference to a class instance of my NPC class, right? Unity will take care of itself once that I use the addComponent on my prefab, while at runtime. Thanks!

Comment: Making your stats class a MonoBehaviour was not quite what Mario meant. You can still keep your stats class as it is and have a connector class that is a MonoBehaviour and that has a reference to the stats class.